# Error: Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA

Tags: entity, jta

I'm making a little project with JSF and came across the error you can read in the title. I have been researching for over an hour and just can't find it, could someone help me out please?!

```
@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public Klant tryRegistreren(String naam, String email, String wachtwoord) {
    try {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("RD_TravelshopPU");
        RequestDispatcher rd = null;
        em = emf.createEntityManager();

        Klant klant = new Klant();
        klant.setNaam(naam);
        klant.setEmail(email);
        klant.setWachtwoord(wachtwoord);

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(klant);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```